# Can displacement output be controlled by light?

Tags: texturing, materials

[image: displacement]

Top one is the texture with displacement output material inserted, bottom one is without. My problem is that on lower and top edges the effect is much harder then in the middle of the brick. I tried using a lot of math nodes before displacement output, but i figured out it isn't texture problem. I tried moving camera back and the effect is similar. It looks like it isnt camera angle either, when i lower the angle texture keeps flat in the middle and sharp at top and bottom edges.

Btw: It there some way of using material nodes controled by light or camera?

[Blender file:](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/ffcced0c)

---

[image]

I tried adding mapping node but no matter how i manipulate coordinates it only moves/stretches texture. It doesnt change the places where displacement is seen better and worse.

I also tried changing displacement type to true (experimental feature). Doesnt help either.

My bricks are not perfectly shaped - example on picture.

What else can I do to manipulate this shadow dependency?

---

[image]

I tried adding mapping node but no matter how i manipulate coordinates it only moves/stretches texture. It doesnt change the places where displacement is seen better and worse.

I also tried changing displacement type to true (experimental feature). Doesnt help either.

My bricks are not perfectly shaped - example on picture.

What else can I do to manipulate this shadow dependency?

Comment: blender stackexchange is not like a forum. please do not add "answers" to your question when they are really just updates. The answer section should be used only for answers to the question. You can [edit](http://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/49556/edit) your question to add more info any time.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your texture coordinates, add a texture coordinate node and a mapping node as vector to your texture used for displace